# Why my image isn't vertically centered on Firefox and IE?

Tags: image, internet-explorer, firefox, vertical-alignment

http://www.jsfiddle.net/PUMqS/

The facebook icon is vertically centered on Opera / Chrome, but not in Firefox / IE.
Do you know why, and how I could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The icon is vertically centered for me in Firefox on Mac.

But note that whether it is or not depends on your exact fonts and how they get rasterized.  If you're on Windows, Firefox and IE are both using DirectWrite for text while Opera and Chrome are using GDI.  You could try turning off hardware acceleration in Firefox to make it use GDI and see if that changes the rendering for you.  If it does, then you need to fix the markup to not depend on the text metrics for the centering...